# $mailer->addAttachment() not sending (or timing out) large files

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Currently I am able to send attachments using Joomla

```
    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();

            ...

    $mailer->addAttachment($filepath);
```

I am able to send attachments of very small sizes (I've tested 1-100KB of different file types INCLUDING .pdf) but when I tried to attach a `1.7mb` pdf file. The page stops loading after some seconds then white screen. I tried to check in developer mode and it says ("Failed to load response data.").

Do you guys know how to go about this? Is this a max upload issue or the request just timed-out maybe because of the slow upload?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will most likely be running out of memory. Can you advise what the memory_limit value is for the hosting service?

Comment: If you use SMTP it may be also limitation of your mail server.